# Javascript magic. Whats going on?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Try:

`` for (const index in [1,2,3]) console.log(`index ${index} equal 1 ? ${index === 1}`, ) ``

```js
for (const index in [1,2,3]) 
  console.log(`index ${index} equal 1 ? ${index === 1}`, )
```

Result:

```
index 0 equal 1 ? false
index 1 equal 1 ? false // << this guy
index 2 equal 1 ? false
```

Expect:

```
index 0 equal 1 ? false
index 1 equal 1 ? true // << this guy
index 2 equal 1 ? false
```

Comment: Sorry, this part of SO is for questions in Russian. Please, use stackoverflow.com for questions in English or translate your question.

Comment: `index === "1"` any array / object key is string.

Comment: Никита, в чём проблема написать вопрос на русском?

Comment: Люди, дайте начинающему презумпцию невиновности, не минусуйте сразу. Человек мог сайты перепутать или не разобраться в разнице разделов.

Comment: Сравнение "'==" преобразует типы сравниваемых значений к одному, а "===" сравнивает без преобразования. Как уже написали - индексы имеют строковый тип.

Comment: vsemozhebuty Прошу прощенья, буду печатать на русском в будущем

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Индексы массива являются строками (array indices are strings):

```js
for (const index in [1,2,3]) console.log(`index ${index} equal 1 ? ${index === '1'}`);
```

Можно использовать нестрогое сравнение (you can use non-strict comparison though):

```js
for (const index in [1,2,3]) console.log(`index ${index} equal 1 ? ${index == 1}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
for (const index in [1,2,3]) 
  console.log(`index ${index} ${typeof index} equal 1 ? ${index === 1}`, )
```